# Help with Normal distribution problem

Tags: normal-distribution

A set of examinations marks is approximately normally distributed with mean of $75$ and standard deviation of $5$. If the top $5\%$ of the students gets Grade A and bottom $25\%$ of gets grade F.
What is the lowest mark in grade A, the highest mark in grade F?

Bottom $25\%$

$X=(-0.5948)\times5+75  $  #Z value of $0.25$ is $-0.5948$

$=72.00$ ( I got the answer as $72$)

Top $5\%$

$X=(Z)\times5+75$

$=0.829*5+75$   # Z value of $0.95$ is $0.8289$

$=79$

I should get answer as $72$ & $83$ (thats how its in my text book) but I'm not getting the correct answer for the  top $5\%$. Did I apply the right procedure?

Comment: Just get the quantiles 0.95 and 0.25 of a Normal distribution with mean 75 and variance 25, you can use software or standardize it to a $N(0,1)$ and use the tables.

Comment: Your mean is 75. What you have to get is the 0.95 quantile. Can you use software or just tables?

Comment: I edited my question . can you please check my question again?

Comment: Edit it with mathematical notation please. For this just embrace your formulas with dollar symbols so you get $X = (-0.5)5$ instead of  X = (-0.5)*5.

Comment: $Z$ value of $0.95$ is not $0.8289$ but $1.6448$

Comment: ok. thanks for your help!!